# compress displayed number for space (like stack but for <1 too)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Strange I can't find an answer on this (probably not searching correctly).

I want to remove all numbers after the first instance of a non-zero number.

For example if I have `0.00208239`, how can I reduce it down to `0.002`, better yet `2m` ([SI units](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Prac/SI.htm))?  This data comes from MySQL but routes through PHP AJAX into an id'd div.

**Note** The first significant digit can be anywhere, from 10^-6 to 10^6.  So, `1,000.77` needs to be `1,000`, or if you're awesome, `1k`.

I'm lamping it with jQuery, so best answer of js, jQuery, MySQL, PHP gets check, but any valid solution of course gets +.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Regular expression?  Perl's `s/([0.]+[1-9])[0-9]*/\1/` translated into PHP...

Comment: so... if it's less than 1, get the first non-zero decimal digit, otherwise round everything off? Is that so?

Comment: @YanickRochon Yeah, I think I could add SI letter if someone could show me how to round and chop off the chaff.  The ideal would be to show it like stack does for big amounts...but also small amounts, so `.001` could be `1m`, but don't worry about the letters.  If someone could show me how to round and chop, I think I could wind my way through applying the SI symbol.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex to get the first number, then use a lookup table to add the suffix:

```
$suffixes = array( 
    -6 => 'µ',
    -5 => '',
    -4 => '',
    -3 => 'm',
    -2 => 'c',
    -1 => '',
     0 => '',
     1 => '',
     2 => '',
     3 => 'k',
     4 => '',
     5 => '',
     6 => 'M',
);

preg_match( '/^[^1-9]*([1-9])/', $str, $matches);
$ten = floor( log( $str, 10));
echo $matches[1] . $suffixes[ $ten ] . "\n";
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23433/discussion-between-nickb-and-joe-coder-guy)

Comment: absolute work of art!  use this to fill in the blanks http://www.unitarium.com/si-prefixes

Answer (score 1):

You could send your data raw and format it before displaying it with JavaScript. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8f4Fa/) :

```
var MACRO_SCALE = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T"];
var MICRO_SCALE = ["", "d", "c", "m", "µ"];

function formatNumber(n) {
    if (n >= 1) {
        n = Math.floor(n);
        var i = 0;
        while (n > 100 && i < MACRO_SCALE.length - 1) {
            n /= 1000;
            i++;
        }
        n = Math.round(n) + MACRO_SCALE[i];
    } else {
        var r = /(\d*)\.([0]*\d{1}?)/.exec(n);
        if (r) {
            n = r[1] + "." + r[2];
        }
        var i = 0;
        while (n < 1 && i < MICRO_SCALE.length - 1) {
            n *= 1000;
            i++;
        }
        n = n + MICRO_SCALE[i];
    }
    return n;
};
```

The advantage of doing so is that you can manipulate (if desired) your raw data instead of re-converting it. After all, data is data and should be formatted only for display, unless you are really concerned about saving a few bytes in data transfer :)

** **Edit** **

I updated the function so that it can be smarter formatting values (and I think the `MICRO_SCALE` formatting was not accurate). It's not idiot proof, but it should be close enough. See the [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/8f4Fa/2/) jsfiddle :

```
// will not likely to go that high/low, but provided anyway
var MACRO_SCALE = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T" /*, "P", "E", "Z", "Y"*/]; 
var MICRO_SCALE = ["", "d", "c", "m", "µ" /*, "n", "p", "f", "a"*/]; 

function formatNumber(n) {
    var r = /(\d*)(\.([0]*\d{1}?).*?(e-(\d+))?)?$/.exec(n);
    if (r) {
        var i = 0;
        var scale;
        //console.log(r);
        if (r[4]) {
            scale = MICRO_SCALE;
            i = Math.abs(r[5]);
            n = r[1];
            while (i >= scale.length) {
                n /= 10; i--;
            }
        } else if (r[1] >= 1) {
            n = r[1]; 
            scale = MACRO_SCALE;
            while (n > 100 && i < scale.length - 1) {
                n /= 1000; i++;
            }
        } else {
            n = parseFloat("0." + r[3]); 
            scale = MICRO_SCALE;   
            while (n < 1 && i < scale.length - 1) {
                n *= 10; i++;
            }
        }
        n += scale[i];
    } else {
        n = 0;
    }

    return n;
};
```

Tested with these values and results

```
0.00208239 ==> 2m
1000.77 ==> 1k
abc ==> 0
0.000000342 (or 3.42e-7) ==> 0.003µ
0.0000234 ==> 0.2µ
1 ==> 1
1.2 ==> 1
```

**Note** : If you want to get `.2µ` instead of `0.2µ`, all you have to do is replace line **34** (`n += scale[i];`) of the jsfiddle with :

```
n = (n < 1 && n > 0 ? (""+n).substring(1) : n) + scale[i];
```